# Sleep after and Hibernate after in Power Options

Tags: windows, sleep, power-management, hibernate

In Power Options, when you change a plan's settings, you have the options to change the `Sleep after` time and `Hibernate after` time:

[image]

I have a couple of questions regarding the different scenarios for these two settings:

- If I set the `Hibernate after` time shorter than the `Sleep after` time, would it mean that the `Sleep after` time is essentially ignored (since a computer can't sleep while it is already in hibernate mode)?
- If I set the `Hibernate after` time longer than the `Sleep after` time, what will be the effect on the machine?

  - will the `Hibernate after` setting be ignored? Or
  - will the computer go from sleep to hibernate? I know that, on my laptop, if it sleeps for a few hours, it will automatically go into hibernate, so is `Hibernate after` the setting that determines how long it will take to go from sleep to hibernate? If that is the case, if I set `Sleep after` to 30 minutes and `Hibernate after` to 60 minutes, will my computer go into hibernate mode after idling for 60 minutes or 90 minutes?

Comment: This seems easy to test.  What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve any problem, I just want to know what exactly these two settings do.

Comment: Try each scenario and see what happens.

Comment: I will do it later today, and post the answer here.

Comment: If the computer has been placed in hibernate mode, the machine isn't even on at that point, so it is pointless to set your machine to sleep after you it has been placed in hibernate.  If the computer is in sleep mode, the machine is technically still on, so it could in theory wake from sleep then hibernate.  One does not normally set both these modes though.